# Invariant Violation: Query(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a component name is `Graph.js` code given below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import Launches from "./Launches.js";
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql"
});

export default class Graph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <View>
          <Text>Hello Apillo</Text>
        </View>
        <Launches />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

And another file name is `Launcher.js` code given below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";

const LAUNCHES_QUERY = gql`
  query LaunchesQuery {
    launches {
      flight_number
      mission_name
    }
  }
`;
export default class Launches extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Query query={LAUNCHES_QUERY}>
          {({ loading, error, data }) => {
            if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
            if (error) return console.log(error);
            let length = data.length;
            console.log(data);
            return <Text>Launches</Text>;
          }}
        </Query>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I setup `graphql` setup in my localhost and it worked well in `http://localhost:4000/graphql`.

When I call URI from react-native app its generated errors.
**Error1**: ***Network error: Network request failed***
**Error2**: ***Invariant Violation: Query(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.***

I also tried to change URI `http://localhost` and given to `http://127.0.0.1`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try with the machine ip

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan ok I will check

Answer (score 1):

The Query component must be outside of , it would be:

```
...
  render() {
    return (
      <Query query={LAUNCHES_QUERY}>
        {({ loading, error, data }) => {
          if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
          if (error) return console.log(error);
          let length = data.length;
          console.log(data);
          return <Text>Launches</Text>;
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Duverney's answer was possibly helpful to others, but I had this issue as well on a React web app, and the cure was to specifically return `null` if there is no data. If you return an empty string, it will fail. Wrapping the return value in JSX also solves the issue. Hopefully that saves someone else a few minutes.

Comment: Hi Ben, could you please elaborate with an example?  I'm going nuts with the same error and my return syntax looks correct... Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I'd have to see your code to be able to show anything helpful. What exactly are you returning from the render function? You can't return nothing (`undefined`), but you can return `null`.

Comment: @joeCarpenter check out this render function and the way the data is being handled and all possible return scenarios are being coded for: https://github.com/tehpsalmist/play-the-mind/blob/3a582f83da71e621c812b1345f55eb162ab144a2/src/screens/Lobby.js#L23

Comment: Thanks you Ben, this is a link to a question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785332/error-on-jest-mount-invariant-violation-nothing-was-returned-from-render