# Error on jest mount: Invariant violation, Nothing was returned from render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, jestjs

I have a react app with some routes setup, which render different stateful components (class components).  I’ve recently added a new route that renders to a stateless component (functional component).   Both the class components and the new functional component use a particular child component (this child component is a functional one).  App works fine, but when adding a new unit test for the route that renders the new functional component my other existing tests started failing with the following error:

> Error: Uncaught [Invariant Violation: HealthCheck(…): Nothing
>   was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is
>   missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.]

This is the code for the recently added functional component:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

import StatusBar from '../../blocks/StatusBar’;


const HealthCheck = () => (<Fragment><StatusBar text=“Health Check“ /></Fragment>);


export default HealthCheck;
```

If I remove the usage of the StatusBar, test pass just fine.  Below is one of my tests (these are the same for each route):

```
test('should render a Route for Dashboard', () => {
  props = { ...props, statusBarProps: { statusBarProps: true };
  // it shows as if it were crashing at mount
  wrap = mount(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/dashboard'']} keyLength={0}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppShell {...props} />
      </Provider>
    </MemoryRouter>,
  );
  // expect(wrap.find(Route).props().path).toEqual('/dashboard');
});
```

**UPDATE**

StatusBar component:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import Text from '../elements/Text';

const ChildrenDiv = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
`;

const ContentDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

`;

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  padding: 28px 56px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  padding: 28px 56px;
`;

const StatusBar = ({
  text,
  children,
}) => (
  <StyledDiv>
    <ContentDiv>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
      <ChildrenDiv>{children}</ChildrenDiv>
    </ContentDiv>
  </StyledDiv>
);

StatusBar.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.node,
};

StatusBar.defaultProps = {
  text: '',
  children: null,
};

export default StatusBar;
```

Comment: What’s your status bar component look like?

Comment: Where is Statusbar code??

Comment: Ben and @hongdevelop please see the updated question with StatusBar

Comment: Having trouble reproducing. You might want to try rebuilding from scratch and evaluating one “building block” at a time to see what changes and what works.

Comment: Thanks Ben!  Yes it is weird, when I replace the <Fragment><StatusBar text=“Health Check“ /></Fragment> with a simple <div>hello world</div> it works fine...